# Make Vertical Data Horizontal on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've downloaded a CSV file which I've imported into Google Sheets. It appears that it has imported in a vertical manner.

[image: 0]

I want the data to be horizontal like this for example

[image: 0]

Is there any way I can do this easily?

Comment: can we use Python and you can execute them with the CSV? or only use Google APP Script?

Answer (score 0):

**Easy way**:

Use `Pivot table`. Put Year in columns and Entity in rows. More [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

**More complex**:

Use the `query formula` with the pivot functionality. More [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(A2:C, "select A,avg(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B")
```

[image: 0]